# nodejs get raw body from POST request

Tags: node.js, express, webhooks

I have an alert in tradingview that send a webhook with a request to my server with a plain body that has some info. the webhook sends PLAIN TEXT, It doecnt sends JSON data.

I was wondering if there is any way to get that plain text data

This is the JSON webhook

[image: WEBHOOK post request]

Then this is the code that I have

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
    
})

app.listen(8080, () => {console.log("listening on port 8080")})
```

Comment: `json.loads`? where have you defined `json`?

Comment: Lawrence, I use that function in flask (python), then Im searching for that but IDK it doecnt work for me

Comment: You say it doesn't send JSON, then you show a screenshot of JSON. Does it send JSON or does it not?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use body parsing middleware.

Your question isn't clear whether the webhook is plain text or JSON. If plain text:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.text());

app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); // If the request has Content-Type text/plain, the body will be parsed as text.
})

app.listen(8080, () => {console.log("listening on port 8080")});
```

If JSON:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); // If the request has Content-Type application/json, the body will be parsed as JSON.
})

app.listen(8080, () => {console.log("listening on port 8080")});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json({limit: '10mb'}));

app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
    const { psw, message }  = req.body
})

app.listen(8080, () => {console.log("listening on port 8080")})
```

this way you can extract body in post request.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:** The `body-parser` middleware is deprecated. The answer provided by @Aurast would be the right way to use the middleware with `express`.

---

You need to add a middleware to parse and extract the body of the HTTP request.

You can install the `body-parser` middleware:

```
$ npm install body-parser
```

And then use it as follows:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.text())
```

Please see this for more information: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: I saw that but body-parse is deprectead so it doecnt work

Comment: I just saw this as well. In that case the answer provided by @Aurast would be the right way to add the middleware.